# Story where America is conquered by all other nations of Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember a science fiction story where America is conquered because every other nation on Earth declared war on it, and America was unwilling to actually fight the entire world, so it surrendered.

As I recall there was no actual precipitating event to the declaration, and the first bunch of nations to declare war were very small and weak ones, like perhaps Lichtenstein or Liberia.

There were scenes showing the UN occupying forces on the streets of an American city.

I have a hunch this may have been a Fred Pohl story. I have checked *The Early Pohl* and *Platinum Pohl* but have not found it. It may have been in the same book as "Poor Superman" and the other postwar American stories, but it was definitely not in the same worldline.  I'm guessing I probably read it during the 1990s, but it is most likely published earlier than 1975, perhaps as early as the 50s.

Although I'm remembering it as `science-fiction`, there really were very few if any actual SF elements in it.

**EDIT**: Duh, "Poor Superman" was Leiber, not Pohl. So it may have been Leiber. Still can't find it.

Comment: Something similar is part of the backstory (it happened before the major events of the books) in Daniel Keyes Moran's series "The Continuing Time." In the early 21st Century, more and more nations got actively involved in helping UN forces to conquer any strong nations (notably the USA and Japan) which were extremely resistant to the idea of the UN becoming a true world government. But those novels only started coming out in the late 1980s, so I suspect this is coincidental, especially if the conquest of the USA was the main plot in what you remember, instead of "it already happened."

Comment: @Lorendiac Thanks, but as you surmise, this is a coincidence. I definitely haven't read those (yet).